# Can FastBlur blur everything behind it?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyside2, qt-quick

I have this code,
qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
ApplicationWindow {
    property var theme: String("#ffffff")
    property var focusColor: String('transparent')
    id: applicationWindow
    visible: false                                      
    width: 600
    height:600
    Image {
        id: image_bug
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "im.png"                                
    }   
    Rectangle {
    width: 100; height: 600
    color: "green"
   Text {
    id: helloText
    text: "Hello world!"
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    font.pointSize: 10; font.bold: true
}
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: { effectSource.width = 1200; effectSource.height = 1200;}
    }
}
    ShaderEffectSource {
        id: effectSource
        sourceItem: image_bug
        anchors.centerIn: image_bug
        width: 300 
        height: 300 
        sourceRect: Qt.rect(x,y, width, height)
    }
    FastBlur{
        id: blur
        anchors.fill: effectSource
        source: effectSource
        radius: 100
    }
}
```

PyQT5 or Pyside2

```
import sys
import os                                                            # +++
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)
    '''
    from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QUrl
    from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QLabel
    from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
    from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
        QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)
    '''
DIR_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
class GUI_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, widget, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('GUI_MainWindow')
        self.resize(600, 600)
        self.widget = widget
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)    
        self.widget_test_2 = QLabel("<h1>Hello World !</h1>", alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.widget_test_2.setObjectName(u"widget_test_2")
        self.widget_test_2.setGeometry(QRect(180, 40, 151, 181))
        self.widget_test_2.raise_()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.widget_test_2)
        layout.addWidget(self.widget, stretch=1)#blur box
if __name__ == "__main__":
    myApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    file = os.path.join(DIR_PATH, "qml_window.qml")                     
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(file)                                      
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    context = engine.rootContext()
    context.setContextProperty("main", engine)
    engine.load(url)
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    widget = QWidget.createWindowContainer(engine.rootObjects()[0])
    window = GUI_MainWindow(widget)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(myApp.exec_())
```

and I want ShaderEffectSource to blur everything behind it,

even widgets created by PyQt5 or PySide2. 
While moving or staying in place

Everything that is behind the widget should be blurry.

I already tried to use the QGraphicsBlurEffect effect for this, but this did not give me the desired results.
I hope FastBlur can do it.
if there are any other options then let me know

Can i do it?

[image]

Comment: In what way QGraphicsBlurEffect did not work for you?

Comment: @musicamante so [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60370144/can-i-blur-the-background-behind-qwidget-menu-pos/60386355?noredirect=1#comment106839083_60386355) 
 I decided to try to solve my problem through FastBlur. because I could not find a solution in QGraphicsBlurEffect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm updating this answer as the question has been partially cleared in the comments, but I will leave the original answer at the end, as it might still be useful.

Besides that, the concept at the base remains the same: a graphics effect is applied to an object, and it modifies *that object* look, not how underlying objects appear. If you want to apply that effect to multiple objects, they have to be *children* of a common parent, and the effect has to be set for *that* parent, but everything that is *below* that parent (and it's not its child) will only be partially affected by the *result* of the effect.
Imagine a blur effect as a filter applied to a real life photograph that is partially transparent: while the image in the photograph is blurred, what you can see behind it will *not* be blurred.

### Subclass the graphics effect

QGraphicsEffects don't provide the ability to limit the extent of their processing, as they usually modify the whole "bounding rect" of the object they are set for.
In order to achieve that, subclassing is necessary and the [`draw()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicseffect.html#draw) method has to be overridden, as it is the one responsible for the actual drawing.

I'm going to presume that the whole interface is going to be affected by the effect in some way: even if some objects are "outside" the rectangle of the effect, they are still part of the same parent, so this is what we're going to do:

- create a main widget that acts as container for the *full* interface
- add a main layout for the *main* interface (the one normally shown)
- create a sub widget that contains the *main* interface, set a layout for it and add anything you need to that layout
- set the subclassed graphics effect to the *sub* widget
- create a widget for the menu, that has the *main widget* as parent, so it will not be part of the main layout; it will have its own layout with its buttons, labels, etc.
- add a system that changes the graphics effect according to the geometry of the menu, and whenever that changes, the effect will be applied to that geometry only

[image: a very very cool menu!]

```
class BlurEffect(QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect):
    effectRect = None

    def setEffectRect(self, rect):
        self.effectRect = rect
        self.update()

    def draw(self, qp):
        if self.effectRect is None or self.effectRect.isNull():
            # no valid effect rect to be used, use the default implementation
            super().draw(qp)
        else:
            qp.save()
            # clip the drawing so that it's restricted to the effectRect
            qp.setClipRect(self.effectRect)
            # call the default implementation, which will draw the effect
            super().draw(qp)
            # get the full region that should be painted
            fullRegion = QtGui.QRegion(qp.viewport())
            # and subtract the effect rectangle
            fullRegion -= QtGui.QRegion(self.effectRect)
            qp.setClipRegion(fullRegion)
            # draw the *source*, which has no effect applied
            self.drawSource(qp)
            qp.restore()


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        background = QtGui.QPixmap('background.png')

        # apply a background to this widget, note that this only serves for the
        # graphics effect to know what's outside the boundaries
        p = self.palette()
        p.setBrush(p.Window, QtGui.QBrush(background))
        self.setPalette(p)

        self.resize(background.size())

        # this layout is only for the child "sub" widget
        mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        mainLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        # the "sub" widget, that contains the main interface
        self.subWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.subWidget)
        # set the background for the subwidget; note that we can't use setPalette()
        # because palette and fonts are inherited by children; using ".QWidget"
        # we ensure that the background is only applied to the subwidget
        self.subWidget.setStyleSheet('''
            .QWidget {
                background-image: url(background.png);
            }
        ''')

        # some random widgets
        subLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.subWidget)
        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
                subLayout.addWidget(btn, row, col)

        btn.setText('Open menu')
        btn.setFocus()
        btn.clicked.connect(self.openMenu)

        # create an instance of our effect subclass, and apply it to the subwidget
        self.effect = BlurEffect()
        self.subWidget.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect)
        self.effect.setEnabled(False)
        self.effect.setBlurRadius(10)

        # create the menu container, that *HAS* to have this main widget as parent
        self.topMenu = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.topMenu.setVisible(False)
        self.topMenu.setFixedWidth(200)
        # move the menu outside the window left margin
        self.topMenu.move(-self.topMenu.width(), 0)

        menuLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.topMenu)
        menuLayout.addSpacing(20)
        for b in range(4):
            btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button {}'.format(b + 1))
            menuLayout.addWidget(btn)

        menuLayout.addSpacing(10)

        closeButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Close menu')
        menuLayout.addWidget(closeButton)
        closeButton.clicked.connect(self.closeMenu)
        # a stretch to ensure that the items are always aligned on top
        menuLayout.addStretch(1)

        # an animation that will move the menu laterally
        self.menuAnimation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation()
        self.menuAnimation.setDuration(500)
        self.menuAnimation.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.OutQuart)
        self.menuAnimation.setStartValue(-self.topMenu.width())
        self.menuAnimation.setEndValue(0)
        self.menuAnimation.valueChanged.connect(self.resizeMenu)
        self.menuAnimation.finished.connect(self.animationFinished)

        # a simple transparent widget that is used to hide the menu when
        # clicking outside it; the event filter is to capture click events
        # it may receive
        self.clickGrabber = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.clickGrabber.installEventFilter(self)
        self.clickGrabber.setVisible(False)

    def resizeMenu(self, value):
        # move the menu and set its geometry to the effect
        self.topMenu.move(value, 0)
        self.effect.setEffectRect(self.topMenu.geometry())

    def openMenu(self):
        if self.topMenu.x() >= 0:
            # the menu is already visible
            return
        # ensure that the menu starts hidden (that is, with its right border
        # aligned to the left of the main widget)
        self.topMenu.move(-self.topMenu.width(), 0)
        self.topMenu.setVisible(True)
        self.topMenu.setFocus()

        # enable the effect, set the forward direction for the animation, and
        # start it; it's important to set the effect rectangle here too, otherwise
        # some flickering might show at the beginning
        self.effect.setEffectRect(self.topMenu.geometry())
        self.effect.setEnabled(True)
        self.menuAnimation.setDirection(QtCore.QVariantAnimation.Forward)
        self.menuAnimation.start()

        # "show" the grabber (it's invisible, but it's there) and resize it
        # to cover the whole window area
        self.clickGrabber.setGeometry(self.rect())
        self.clickGrabber.setVisible(True)
        # ensure that it is stacked under the menu and above everything else
        self.clickGrabber.stackUnder(self.topMenu)

    def closeMenu(self):
        # in case that the menu has changed its size, set again the "start" value
        # to its negative width, then set the animation direction to backwards
        # and start it
        self.menuAnimation.setStartValue(-self.topMenu.width())
        self.menuAnimation.setDirection(QtCore.QVariantAnimation.Backward)
        self.menuAnimation.start()
        # hide the click grabber
        self.clickGrabber.setVisible(False)

    def animationFinished(self):
        # if the animation has ended and the direction was backwards it means that
        # the menu has been closed, hide it and disable the effect
        if self.menuAnimation.direction() == QtCore.QVariantAnimation.Backward:
            self.topMenu.hide()
            self.effect.setEnabled(False)

    def focusNextPrevChild(self, next):
        if self.topMenu.isVisible():
            # a small hack to prevent tab giving focus to widgets when the
            # menu is visible
            return False
        return super().focusNextPrevChild(next)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if source == self.clickGrabber and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            # the grabber has been clicked, close the menu
            self.closeMenu()
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        # always set the menu height to that of the window
        self.topMenu.setFixedHeight(self.height())
        # resize the grabber to the window rectangle, even if it's invisible
        self.clickGrabber.setGeometry(self.rect())
        if self.topMenu.isVisible():
            # resize the effect rectangle
            self.effect.setEffectRect(self.topMenu.geometry())
```

---

### Previous answer

Since you want to apply the effect to the underlying objects, I believe that the solution is to use a "container" to embed them, and then apply the blur effect to that. The same concept would be applied with QGraphicsBlurWidget too.

```
ApplicationWindow {
    property var theme: String("#ffffff")
    property var focusColor: String('transparent')
    id: applicationWindow
    visible: false                                      
    width: 600
    height:600

    Rectangle {
        id: container
        anchors.fill: parent

        Image {
            id: image_bug
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: "im.png"                                
        }

        Rectangle {
            width: 100; height: 600
            color: "green"
            Text {
                id: helloText
                text: "Hello world!"
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                font.pointSize: 10; font.bold: true
            }
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: { effectSource.width = 1200; effectSource.height = 1200;}
            }
        }
    }

    ShaderEffectSource {
        id: effectSource
        sourceItem: container
        anchors.centerIn: image_bug
        width: 300 
        height: 300 
        sourceRect: Qt.rect(x,y, width, height)
    }

    FastBlur{
        id: blur
        anchors.fill: effectSource
        source: effectSource
        radius: 100
    }
}
```

[image: resulting full blur effect]

Comment: So it’s impossible to blur `QLabel("Hello World!")` which is outside of container?Ok you said that the concept can be applied to QGraphicsBlurEffect.But QGraphicsBlurEffect erodes everything that is in it the only parameter that it has is `setBlurRadius()`Creating a frame like in ShaderEffectSource is not possible.and if you create a container and assign it `QRect (4,2,300,300)`It will either be empty or contain a copy of the entire menu.If it contains a copy of the entire menu then the blur effect will not be updated and when moving,you get such a bug[img](https://i.ibb.co/G2ZZsg9/jhkjnn.gif)

Comment: I apologize if this sounded somehow confusing

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand what you meant... Can you try to clarify?

Comment: OK I will try. But I do not speak English well.
I'm trying to make such a pull-down menu
[img](https://i.ibb.co/x8pjnfB/ggff.gif) 
but only in PyQT5
I am looking for different solutions for this issue
you said **The same concept would be applied with QGraphicsBlurWidget too.**
I didn’t find the parameter `ShaderEffectSource {width: 300; height: 300}` in QGraphicsBlurWidget
and I don’t know how QGraphicsBlurWidget will respond to QPropertyAnimation

Comment: Can you write a usage example QGraphicsBlurWidget in this
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60370144/can-i-blur-the-background-behind-qwidget-menu-pos/60386355?noredirect=1#comment106839083_60386355) ?

Comment: Ok, I understand that English is not your native language, but both your code and your image were misleading (and they were in your previous question also). If you had shown the image you just linked in your question at first, that would have been more clear. I'm updating the answer right now, even if it's not completely related to the actual question, but I suggest you to be more careful in the future and try to be more clear about your questions, and, if images are required, provide actual examples of what you want to achieve.

Comment: I understood you. Thank you for giving such a detailed answer.